# Derivative of Matrix with respect to Matrix notation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, adaptive-control

I was reading my adaptive control textbook, and I noticed that my professor used a notation that is somehow confusing me.

$$J\left(\Theta\right) = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^T\epsilon$$
where $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow J\in \mathbb{R}$. When taking the derivative of the scalar with respect to the matrix $\Theta$, he writes it as

$$\frac{\partial J^T}{\partial\Theta^T}$$
instead of
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial\Theta}$$

Can someone explain the meaning of the former notation of the derivative?

Comment: I guess it is a layout matter, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions.

Comment: I asked my professor, he said that it is just a notation to take a derivative with respect to a matrix among the vectors. Also, he said that $J^T = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\epsilon^T \rightarrow \frac{\partial J^T}{\partial \Theta^T} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial \Theta^T} \epsilon^T$, but $J^T$ is a scalar, while $\epsilon\epsilon^T$ is a matrix.

Comment: How would you get a matrix by transposing $J = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^T \epsilon$? $J^T = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^T \epsilon$.

Comment: @user550103 Exactly. The proposed definition is so wrong.